# Why can't I submit this edit? “Body must be at least 30 characters, you entered 0”

Tags: support, edits, markdown

I am referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338578/get-the-first-5-and-last-2-chars-of-a-string) where a user gave an answer, but the user has **quoted** the code instead of formatting it. But, when I tried to edit it, this is what I got:

[image]

So, am I going to be enlightened or is Stack Overflow being a pain in the arse again?

Answer (score 15):

According to your screen shot, you didn't indent the code, and the first character is a `<`.  The error message says *"Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0"*, which means that the Markdown editor interpreted your text as an HTML tag, and didn't count the characters in that tag.

Comment: ...which should also be fairly visible in the preview, which was probably empty.

Answer (score 1):

Select your HTML/PHP code and click on curly braces, **{ }**.